# Unable to send cross-domain request in `Firefox` extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, firefox, firefox-addon

I am trying to access `cross-domain` data by using `jsonp` or `XMLHttpRequest` with `GET` method. My Code:

**XMLHttpRequest**

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "http://example.com/ajax.php?code=BSE", true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
        alert(xhr.responseText);
    }
xhr.send();
```

**JsonP**

```
$.ajax({
     type: 'GET',
     url: "http://example.com/ajax.php?code=BSE",
     dataType: "jsonp",
     jsonpCallback: "jsonp_callback",
     crossDomain: true,
     success: function(res){
         console.log(res);
     }
});
```

Both methods having same behavior. Whenever i am sending request its just keep loading (even i am not sure its sending request or not) and do nothing.

And my php code:

**PHP Code:**

```
header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
$dts=array('value'=>'123');
echo $_GET['jsonp_callback'] . '('.json_encode($dts).')';
```

Comment: yes.. all another jquery functions are working fine..

Comment: the same `XMLHttpRequest` working perfect in chrome extension..

Comment: `jsonpCallback: "jsonp_callback",`  is this callback function actually exist

Comment: I hope the edit that was made on your behalf fixed a typo you made, because now, the XHR code is valid

Comment: @Alive to Die: i do not know much more about `jsonp` really

Comment: @Jaromanda X: yea..

Comment: `$.ajax({
     type: 'GET',
     url: "http://example.com/ajax.php?code=BSE",
     dataType: "jsonp",
     success: function(res){
         console.log(res);
     }
});`  try this once @RahulSharma

Comment: if this is a web extension that works in chrome, there's a 90% chance it will work in firefox - you say there's no indication if the request is even sent? not even in the browser console (ctrl+shift+j)

Comment: @Jaromanda X: yes, i am running extension by command: `jpm run -b "C:\Program Files\Nightly\firefox.exe"` when browser running its not showing any request in console or network.

Comment: oh ... [jpm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK) ... that's not a [web extension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions)

Comment: running using jpm..

Comment: to execute extension in development mode i am using jpm to run un-signed browser extension: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Getting_Started_(jpm)

Comment: is there any another better way to develop firefox extension ?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that duplicates the problem. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: @Makyen: try to understand, i am on topic.. i just developed the firefox extension and in extension i used jquery and in my extension i have to call cross platform api to get some data.. still you think my question is differ?

Comment: At this point it is **highly** recommended that any new extension development use [WebExtensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions). [**All other extension types will be removed from Firefox with Firefox version 57**, expected on 2017-11-14.](https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2017/02/16/the-road-to-firefox-57-compatibility-milestones/) WebExtensions are code-compatible with Chrome (with inconsistencies due to two different implementations and WebExtensions not supporting everything Chrome does, and vise versa).

Comment: @RahulSharma, No, the question is not on-topic. This is a debugging question. That means [that it must contain a [mcve] which, using only the code provided in the question, duplicates the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). There is not enough code in the question to duplicate the problem. There are multiple possible problems which we have to *guess* if they might be the cause with only knowing the code currently in the question.

Comment: The reason that a [mcve] is required is that *we want to help*. It is **much** easier to help if we don't have to recreate any of the code needed to duplicate the problem. This is code that you already have. So, please help us to help you and provide a *complete* [mcve] that duplicates the problem. Without a [mcve], the amount of effort required to even begin to help you is **much** higher, which *significantly* reduces the number of people willing/able to help you. Even if we put out the extra effort, we have to **guess** at significant portions of what your problem might be.

Answer (score 5):

The `XMLHttpRequest` will work just fine, no need for jsonp. In your `manifest.json`, make sure you request permissions for the domain you are posting to -- Chrome doesn't require permissions for XHR, but Firefox does. This error manifests in Firefox as a http code 404 in the XHR, but no activity in the network panel. If you get a http code 0, you have CORS or mixed content security issues as well.

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "web extension",
  "version": "1",
  "permissions": [
    "http://example.com/"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      // ...
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: oh god, you saved my life, it is so stealth option... topic caster can mark this answer as needed!

Comment: Thank you, it is not needed in chrome but it is in Firefox

Answer (score -1):

Try using `new XDomainRequest()` in your xhr request. XDomainRequest is an implementation of HTTP access control (CORS).

```
var createCORSRequest = function(method, url) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  if ("withCredentials" in xhr) {
    // Most browsers.
    xhr.open(method, url, true);
  } else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined") {
    // IE8 & IE9
    xhr = new XDomainRequest();
    xhr.open(method, url);
  } else {
    // CORS not supported.
    xhr = null;
  }
  return xhr;
};

var url = 'http://example.com/ajax.php?code=BSE';
var method = 'GET';
var xhr = createCORSRequest(method, url);

xhr.onload = function() {
  // Success code goes here.
};

xhr.onerror = function() {
  // Error code goes here.
};


xhr.setRequestHeader('content-type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
xhr.send();
```